# Highlight cell if same value present in another sheet's cell

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

Example -
Client has a master list of client's hosted domains in sheet 1.

Client keeps list of actual A record verified domains in use in sheet 2.

What I need is to highlight domains in sheet 2 which match domains in sheet 1 using a color, and highlight domains in sheet 2 a different color if they do not appear in sheet 1.

(Domains in master list which match A record entered domains in sheet 1 appear in Green, domains which do not match list appear in red)

The column names on both sheets are "domain".

Answer (score 0):

Add a helper columns in each, say H, with formulae like:

```
=--countif(Sheet1!B:B,B1) >0
```

copied down to suit (assuming domains are in ColumnB - change `Sheet1` to suit actual sheet names).

Then apply Conditional Formatting rules of:

```
=H1
```

and:

```
=H1<>TRUE
```

to Ranges B:B

with colours to suit.

**Correction**

The above was based on my misreading the question (I thought some highlighting was to apply to each sheet): Instead please try, in say H1 of Sheet2 and copied down to suit:

```
=--countif(Sheet1!B:B,B1) >0
```

and these two rules:

[image: SO25985746 example]

where the first is:

```
=and(H1<>"",H1<>TRUE)
```

(the first part of which is to avoid blank cells being highlighted).

Comment: I'm sure you're on the right track here, I think I just need the google spreadsheets for VBA idiots version. Sheet1 is named "Active" so I created this in cell N `=--countif(Active!B:B,B1) >0` (You are correct that domains are in column B actually). Then, I dragged that cell all the way down where it's showing "ERROR" for now. I'm not sure where to go from there w/ the conditional formatting rules and so on, Would those need to go on the second sheet (named anything, doesn't matter really I can name to suit).

Comment: Yes, new Google sheets - I thought it used VBA on the back end as I'm only used to working with Excel. I'd really rather put all this into a mysql and php app but client is a Google Sheets only type guy.

Comment: I don't get the "custom formula" option in conditional format at all for some reason.